# WPF How to make listbox items editable?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I need to add the "edit selected item" functionality to my listbox. Basically I need either of two:

- Ctrl+Click on list item and it magically becomes an editable textbox or something and when edited update the data in the database.
- Press the "Edit" Button under my ListBox, open the new Edit Window, edit the data there, update the database and update the ListBox when the Edit Window is closed.

Problems I encountered:

- I want to have the first variant of the solution but I really don't know how to implement that.
- Implementing the second variant I didn't get how should I update the ListBox after editing the selected item in a new Window.

Here's my XAML of ListBox:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="LstQueries" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="228" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="482" FontFamily="HelveticaNeueCyr" FontSize="16" ItemsSource="{Binding Queries}" MouseDoubleClick="LstQueries_MouseDoubleClick">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Medium" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Helvetica"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Helvetica"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button x:Name="BtnEdit" Content="Edit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,228,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="482" Height="43" Click="BtnEdit_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

And here's what my Edit Window XAML like:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="TxtName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="99,13,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="183" FontFamily="HelveticaNeueCyr" FontSize="16"/>
    <Label Content="Name:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="HelveticaNeueCyr" FontSize="16"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="TxtText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="116" Margin="65,45,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="217" FontFamily="HelveticaNeueCyr" FontSize="16"/>
    <Label Content="Text:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,86,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="HelveticaNeueCyr" FontSize="16" Height="27" Width="50"/>
    <Button x:Name="BtnSave" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,166,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132" Height="33"/>
    <Button x:Name="BtnCancel" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,166,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132" Height="33" Click="BtnCancel_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

And here's how I access the SelectedItem in the ListBox:

```
if (LstQueries.SelectedIndex < 0) return;
dynamic item = LstQueries.SelectedItem as dynamic;
string name = item.Name;
string text = item.Text;
```

'Queries' that are binded to the listBox is the `ObservableCollection<Query>` where `Query` looks like this:

```
public class Query
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Autoschool { get; set; }
}
```

So, could you help me please with implementing either of solutions?

Comment: so you have your selected item, you have an edit button, i'm not too sure what's the problem ... Filip answer seems fair enough as well.

Comment: @Noctis Well, the problem is that it would be quite an ugly solution to pass the data back and forth between windows in constructors or something like that, I wanted to find out how to use bindings efficiently in that case. But the first solution (the magical one) would be way better anyway:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use dynamic? You can cast `SelectedItem` to `Query` without problem. Once you have it, all you need to do is load properties into your Edit Window and handle editing here.

Your Query needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Otherwise you won't see changes in `ListBox` (because the control is not aware of them). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229614(v=vs.100).aspx

Also, it would be easier to use `Binding`. Don't forget to set the Binding mode to `TwoWay` so your properties get updated once you change them. http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/04/20/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-and-wp7-part-two.html

For your window. Prepare there single `Query` property (named SelectedQuery for example) to which you set your selected instance. You can then bind your TextBoxes (in window) using something like this: `Text="{Binding SelectedQuery.Name, Mode="TwoWay"}"`. If you have corretly implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` changing text in your window should immediately change it in your `ListView`.

Comment: Could you please go into more detail about those bindings? I've looked through the articles you provided and I implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` in my `Query` class. And also I've added `Mode=TwoWay` in the ListBox.ItemTemplate Binding. But what should I do to actually pass the data to the new window and make them appear there, and after that, after clicking the Save button how do I make the ListBox update? Where exactly should I add those bindings?

Comment: Yeah, everything now works cool! But if I want to cancel the editing, what should I do? I mean that I'd like to make changes only after I click the Save Button, but they happen any time I edit the data in the bew window.

Comment: @DenisYakovenko you can save original values somewhere and when Save button is not clicked restore them for examplr.

Answer (score 2):

You could tackle this in different ways. 
In a project I wrote once, I wanted to have a double click on an item open up the edit window for that item. 
I've opted to go with the `i.Interaction.Triggers` . The specific code looks like :

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
        <Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding EditExercise_Command}" 
                  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=LastExercises_ListView
                                            ,Path=SelectedItem}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Now, whenever I double click an item, it opens the window to edit it. 
This was using MVVM, so I didn't want to have code in my code behind.

You'll have to reference this dll: `system.windows.interactivity.dll`, and you'll probably want to read a bit about their usage. Here's [an article about that](https://coreclr.wordpress.com/2011/01/05/using-interaction-triggers-in-mvvm/).

Here's the full listbox code (the relevant bits at least):

```
   <ListBox x:Name="..."  
              ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredCollection}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedExercise, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              ...
              >
        <ListBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header ="Edit Exercise"   
                          Command="{Binding EditExercise_Command}" 
                          CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedExercise}"
                />
                <MenuItem Header ="Delete Exercise" 
                          Command="{Binding DeleteExercise_Command}" 
                          CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedExercise}"
                />
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListBox.ContextMenu>

        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding EditExercise_Command}" 
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=LastExercises_ListView
                                                                 , Path=SelectedItem}" 
                />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    </ListBox>
```

You also get extra right click menu options in case you don't want to double click, or if you want to delete that item (with a different command)